# Suppress delimiter option in Camel Recipient List

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

We have a custom camel processor which needs to be invoked and also parametrized dynamically from the incoming request payload xpath, but the URI of the processor contains 'COMMA' as it makes SQL query internally

```
<context id="mycontext">
   <from uri="timer://com.arpit.timer?period=1000&amp;delay=1000&amp;repeatCount=5&amp;fixedRate=false&amp;daemon=false"/>
    <setBody>
        <simple> "here goes sample XML payload "</simple>
    </setBody>
    <setheader headerName="val1">
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String"> "here goes my xpath" </xpath>
    </setheader>
 <!-- Now I call my custom processor with URI containing comma -->
    <recipientList delimiter="%">
        <simple>Select col1, col2, col3 from tablex where id = '${header.val1}'</simple>
    </recipientList>
</context>
```

Now the scenario works only when we give **delimiter="%"** otherwise, it fails with error about not able to find end point col2.

Is there a way to suppress delimiter in RECIPIENT LIST?

Regards,
Arpit.

Comment: Went through the `org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList` class and following line of code in the class make it looks like really can't have this suppression? `public boolean sendToRecipientList(Exchange exchange, Object recipientList, AsyncCallback callback) {
        Iterator<Object> iter = ObjectHelper.createIterator(recipientList, delimiter); .......}`  Can someone confirm if my understanding is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot suppress the delimiter. Though you can set it to a value which wont match, eg such as XXXXXXXXXXX or whatever.

I logged a ticket to allow doing this in a future Camel release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6665